# Does Apache Ignite client communicate with other Ignite client?

Tags: ignite

We have a cluster of ignite server nodes.
Also we have multiple ignite nodes running in client mode.
We see that ignite client is listening to 47100 and 10800.
Due to some issue, we dont want unknown connections to these ports, so we allowed only ignite server ips to access the port that opened in ignite client.

Trying to understand whether ignite  client also communicates with other ignite client to share any info or for topology change etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 47100..47199 are default ports for `TcpCommunicationSpi` protocol, which is used to communicate between nodes (both server and client nodes):
  perform cache operations, transactions, etc. You should not block them.
- 10800..10899 are default ports for incoming thin client / JDBC / ODBC connections (**not** client nodes). And, yes, thin client can be connected to a client node. If such thin clients are undesired, you can disable thin client connector by setting `ClientConnectorConfiguration` to `null` in `IgniteConfiguration`. More details can be found [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/thin-clients/getting-started-with-thin-clients#configuring-thin-client-connector).

##### Note about direct client connections

> Trying to understand whether ignite client also communicates with other ignite client to share any info or for topology change etc...

Most of time client nodes communicate only with server ones, because client node does not store data. But direct connections between client nodes are possible in some cases, for example, when performing compute operations. Code below leads to establishing direct  communications between clients (`client` is supposed to be a client node):

```
ClusterGroup clients = client.cluster().forClients();

// Client calls compute API over cluster group, which includes only clients.
client.compute(clients).broadcast(() -> System.out.println(">>>>>> Run on client"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, May i know why ignite client expose 10800, why there would be a thin client trying to connect to this port.

As you suggested, we are going to try setting it as null, but wanted to understand why by default it is opening up the port?

Comment: Thick client node is still node, so it can handle client (thin, JDBC, ODBC, REST) requests acting as a "gateway" to cluster. All nodes open this port by default.

Comment: Also we are not able to find the this in our ignite code  "client.compute(clients).broadcast(() -> System.out.println(">>>>>> Run on client"))" .   Our ignite version is 2.10.


Also your sugggestion of setting "ClientConnectorConfiguration to null" . Is there any document mentioning the same.

Comment: what may be a possible reason if my service able to connect with server node but not with client node

Comment: @vigneshwaranBalakrishnan , how do you start client instance? Please, check documentation for 2.10: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.10.0/distributed-computing/distributed-computing#broadcasting-a-task

Comment: @RitvikRohatgi , can you clarify what exactly you try to do?

Comment: @vigneshwaranBalakrishnan , I can not find any explicit documentation about setting up "ClientConnectorConfiguration to null", but you can check ClientListenerProcessor source code [here](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/4633ca4f2cc88949579ce2de213252fa0a0f8471/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/odbc/ClientListenerProcessor.java#L495-L496).